# One Pica Avalara Avatax Magento Extension compatibility with Magento Enterprise Edition 1.13, has anyone tried to integrate the two yet?

Tags: magento, magento-1.13, avalara

I have been tasked with integrating the One Pica Avalara Avatax extension into a Magento 1.13.0.2 project.

Installation was easy enough and the module appears to be functioning correctly on the backend. However, the client does not yet have account credentials with Avalara, so I can't test the extension with the newest version of Magento. I was wondering if anyone here has integrated the Avatax extension into the latest version of Magento successfully. My concern is that with Magento's latest update (which includes major changes to Tax Calculations) will there be conflicts between Avatax and the new core code?

Thank you,

Emil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest available version of the One Pica Avalara Magento Extension is is 2.4.3.1 (May 16, 2013). It can be obtained via Magento Connect or downloaded directly from OnePica's website.

The extension supports all current versions of Magento Community after 1.2 and current versions of Magento Enterprise after 1.5.

Hopefully this helps!